# 301-Redirect redirects properly, but doesn't transfer Page Rank or other SEO value

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I'm wondering why a series of 301-redirects I implemented on a site properly redirect the browser to the appropriate page, but do NOT pass through SEO value (as calculated using MozBar and PR plugin for Chrome).

Are there common reasons that might cause this issue?  My initial thought was that I made a mistake in the 301-redirects, but if the page window is correctly rendering the final destination page, I'm stumped as to why seemingly 0% of SEO value is transferring correctly.  I know that 301-redirects do not transfer 100% of 'SEO juice', but 0% seems underwhelming.

The former pages weren't amazing in terms of page rank, but they weren't completely devoid of value...

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide the URL so we can check it out the redirects? Also, what do you mean by a "series of 301-redirects"? Is there more than one redirect?

Comment: Hi Seano, one relevant link is [ListGiant](http://www.listgiant.com/lists) , which does not display any PageRank in the toolbar, nor the Moz variants of DA and PA.  As is noted in the below answer by iSaumya, it appears that Google may not be pushing any updated data to the PageRank checker as users increasingly favor other trust signals.  By 'series of 301-redirects', I mean that there are two 301-redirects in the chain, essentially migrating URL A.php to URL B.html, which was then migrated again to URL C.

Comment: Typically you want to limit the number of redirects, but two redirects shouldn't be a big deal. Can you show me the original URL you're redirecting? Not the end state URL (http://www.listgiant.com/lists).

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you actually done the 301 redirect properly then googlebot will pass the ranks to the redirected site. But if you are talking about Google PageRank, then I must have to tell you that google has come a long way with its algorithm and actually made it very advanced. In fact google actually decided to roll out any more Pagrank update in future (as per google webmaster hangout talk) so now with Panda and many other advanced algorithm, Google will give higher preference to those sites who have better quality content and satisfy more users. But ofcourse if your site has been backlinked by lifehacker or CNN or any authority website, you will get higher priorit. But no of backlinks doesn't matter now, its all about quality now. Quality content and Quality Backlink.

**Then Why I'm got getting the SEO juice?**

Well actually you are getting the seo juice from your 301 redirect but you are unable to see that (and will be in future) as google won't update pagerank.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi iSaumya, Thanks for the response.  To clarify, you're saying that Google has decided to **not** roll out any further PageRank updates, correct?  Researching this topic on webmasterworld and seoroundtable seems to corroborate your point that Google no longer intends to send rank updates to the toolbar.  Very interesting.